How can i set WiFi configuration into an NFC tag, so that when tapped it automatically connects to the network?
i am trying to develop a java aplication in Android Studio. In this app i want to set some WiFi credentials to a tag so that when a user taps on the tag it automatically connects them to the WiFi i have set. I understand that for this to happen i need to provide the SSID and the password of the network i am trying to configure
I know that the NFC functionality works in general in my app because i am able to write URLs, text and set and unset password protection. What i have tried is the following. I receive a Tag, and two strings (the ssid and the password) in my Main.java activity. I was developing a new class called NFCUtils.java that makes the following:
public class NFCUtils{

public static void writeWifiConfigToTag(Tag tag, String ssid, String password) {
    NdefRecord ssidRecord = createTextRecord(ssid, Locale.getDefault(), true);
    NdefRecord passwordRecord = createTextRecord(password, Locale.getDefault(), true);
    NdefMessage wifiMessage = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime("application/vnd.wfa.wsc",
            ssid.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)),
            ssidRecord,
            passwordRecord);

    // Write the NdefMessage to the tag
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    try {
        ndef.connect();
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(wifiMessage);
        ndef.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static NdefRecord createTextRecord(String payload, Locale locale, boolean encodeInUtf8) {
    byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? StandardCharsets.UTF_8 : StandardCharsets.UTF_16;
    byte[] textBytes = payload.getBytes(utfEncoding);

    int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
    byte[] status = { (byte) (utfBit + langBytes.length) };

    byte[] data = new byte[status.length + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(status, 0, data, 0, status.length);
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, status.length, langBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, status.length + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);

    return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
}
}

Apparently everything works fine, but when i try to scan the Tag, nothing happens. Can someone exaplin me what is happening?
Thank you in advance for your time!

Does this answer your question? Share Wifi credentials via NFC tag without special apps

hi again @Andrew and thanks for your quick response! I was taking a llok to the solution you gave me. And i see that function handleWriteNfcEvent is what i need. However i don't know what is the mWpsNfcConfigurationToken it is referring to there. it is obtained through mWifiManager.getWpsNfcConfigurationToken(mAccessPoint.networkId); but i can see that there is no method getWpsNfcConfigurationToken in WifiManager.
Could you please help me in this? Where can i find this token? And moreover i see that he only uses password as input but not the ssid? Why is this? Thanks in advance

There were various solutions there but that one from memory said, if you rooted your device you could get the detail automatically (using the undocumented getWpsNfcConfigurationToken) otherwise the user would have to provide ssid and passwrods instead (which that had support for as well)
